# Facebook Graph Pagination loses query on future pages

Tags: facebook-graph-api, pagination

Let's say I want to search for McDonalds in a certain location using Facebook's graph API, [like so.](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3DMcDonalds%26limit%3D200%26center%3D41.8883%2C-87.6357%26distance%3D8047%26fields%3Did%2Cname%26type%3Dplace&version=v2.0) Now, since I know that Facebook won't always give me back all the results I want on the first page, or even the number of results I asked for, I follow the pagination link. [This](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=search%3Ffields%3Did%252Cname%26limit%3D200%26type%3Dplace%26center%3D41.8883%252C-87.6357%26distance%3D8047%26offset%3D200%26__after_id%3Denc_AewM_OgChZN-f9t0S3QTGJrIu6YKZHdBMiMZpz4iNp7I8tpZfhdG_bKDW4q_976kIGUebZT_Iw6gY3TKBENhkJJ5&version=v2.0) is the one I was given. Now, this second page loses the query string, and returns a bunch of results near the search location, but having nothing at all to do with McDonalds (e.g. Tufenkian Artisan Carpets Chicago). How can I tell when I have no more applicable results, if the pagination drops my original query entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like removing the limit parameter causes pagination to correctly have the query on future pages: see the [same search](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3DMcDonalds%26center%3D41.8883%2C-87.6357%26distance%3D8047%26fields%3Did%2Cname%26type%3Dplace&version=v2.0) without the limit parameter.